# Angles for quaternion converter

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was referring to an API [documentation](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf2/html/c++/classbtQuaternion.html#_details) on Quarternion related stuff. I want to use the last constructor which is written "Constructor from Euler angles". The constructor itself is as below:

```
btQuaternion::btQuaternion ( const btScalar & yaw,
                             const btScalar & pitch,
                             const btScalar & roll   
                           )
```

My question is regarding the angles. Should the angles in the input argument be in degree or radian?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11776/angles-for-quaternion-converter/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Always radians, degree are never used.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Radians.  They are the standard, see [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4